# ООП для арифметических операций с матрицами в Java

Tags: java

Хочу написать для себя библиотеку для работы с матрицами.
Думаю как обеспечить чтобы над элементами матрицы можно было производить арифметические операции.

Есть ли в **Java SE** интерфейсы, которые объявляют методы типа `add()`, `subtract()` и т.д.?
Насколько я понял, класс [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) в этом не поможет, да он и не сильно подходит сюда, ведь элементами матрицы будут не обязательно числа.

Answer (score 2):

Решил сделать просто абстрактный класс Matrix, в нем основные методы для операциями над матрицами.
От него наследуются три класса: IntegerMatrix, DoubleMatrix и 
MatrixOfElements, где Element обеспечивает необходимую возожность выдполнения арифметических операция над элементами матрицы.

Comment: В качестве примера можете посмотреть как реализовано ООП для работы с матрицами в [Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/package-summary.html).